# Return only a single value for a column in cases where there are multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I would like to return a single arbitrarily selected value for a query against a data source that has multiple rows.

### The raw data

```
user_id   account   role
paa2013   52501050  PD/PI
paa2013   52501050  Principal Investigator
```

### What I want

```
user_id   account   role
paa2013   52501050  PD/PI
```

### My query

```
select distinct 
  user_id, 
  account,
  case 
    when role = 'PD/PI' then 'PD/PI'
    when role = 'Principal Investigator' then 'Principal Investigator'
  end  
from table
where account = '52501050' 
group by 
  user_id, 
  account,
  case 
    when role = 'PD/PI' then 'PD/PI'
    when role = 'Principal Investigator' then 'Principal Investigator'
  end
```

### What I get

```
user_id   account   role
paa2013   52501050  PD/PI
paa2013   52501050  Principal Investigator
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you only have those two values *(`PD/PI` and `Principal Investigator`)*?  Or are there other values in the `role` column?  And which SQL Dialect are you using?  *(MySQL, MS SQL Server, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc?)*

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. There are 5,000 rows with different combinations of person IDs, accounts, and roles. The ultimate goal is to return one role per account and person ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To literally answer your question, you just need to use `MAX()` as `PD` comes after `Pr`.

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  account,
  MAX(role)   AS max_role
FROM
  table
WHERE
  account = '52501050'
GROUP BY
  user_id,
  account
```

To be more generalised there are a lot of options.

```
WITH
  roles AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS rank, 'PD/PI' AS role
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS rank, 'Principal Investigator' AS role
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS rank, 'another' AS role
),
  grouped_data AS
(
  SELECT
    table.user_id,
    table.account,
    MIN(roles.rank)  AS min_role_rank
  FROM
    table
  INNER JOIN
    roles
      ON roles.role = table.role
  GROUP BY
    table.user_id,
    table.account
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  grouped_data
INNER JOIN
  roles
    ON roles.role = grouped_data.min_role_rank
```

Or...

```
WITH
  ranked_data AS
(
  SELECT
    table.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table.user_id,
                                    table.account
                           ORDER BY role_rank.id
                      )
                         AS user_role_rank
  FROM
    table
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      CASE table.role
        WHEN 'PD/PI'                  THEN 1
        WHEN 'Principal Investigator' THEN 2
        WHEN 'an other'               THEN 3
                                      ELSE 4
      END
          AS id
  )
    role_rank
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ranked_data 
WHERE
  user_role_rank = 1
```

Or...

```
WITH
  roles AS
(
  SELECT 1 AS rank, 'PD/PI' AS role
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS rank, 'Principal Investigator' AS role
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS rank, 'another' AS role
),
  ranked_data AS
(
  SELECT
    table.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table.user_id,
                                    table.account
                           ORDER BY roles.rank
                      )
                         AS user_role_rank
  FROM
    table
  INNER JOIN
    roles
      ON roles.role = table.role
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  ranked_data 
WHERE
  user_role_rank = 1
```

In a more perfect world, you would have one `user` or `account` table, that is constrained so that this can't happen.  Then a second `user_role` table for the 0..many roles that a user/account may be associated to.

```
 id | account                user_id | role_id
----+---------              ---------+---------
 11 | aaaaaaa                   11   |     1
 22 | bbbbbbb                   11   |     2
                                22   |     2
                                22   |     3
```

Then you'd have a `role` table with things such as the ranking ordinals....

```
 role_id | rank | name | etc
---------+------+------+-----
     1   |  30  |  aa  | ???
     2   |  10  |  bb  | ???
     3   |  20  |  cc  | ???
```

Then the query becomes relatively concise...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  user
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 role.*
    FROM user_role
    JOIN role ON role.id = user_role.role_id
   WHERE user_role.user_id = user.user_id
ORDER BY role.rank
)
  AS role
```

*(This demonstrates both a different structure and a different approach, either or both may be helpful to you)*

***EDIT***:

I've also noticed that `SQL SERVER` now supports `WITH TIES` to ive yet another approach.  *(Similar to the `ROW_NUMBER()` approach, with slight shorter code...

```
  SELECT TOP(1) WITH TIES
    table.*
  FROM
    table
  CROSS APPLY
  (
    SELECT
      CASE table.role
        WHEN 'PD/PI'                  THEN 1
        WHEN 'Principal Investigator' THEN 2
        WHEN 'an other'               THEN 3
                                      ELSE 4
      END
          AS id
  )
    role_rank
  ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY table.user_id,
                                    table.account
                           ORDER BY role_rank.id
                      )
```

This can be confusing at first.  It selects the first row *(`TOP(1)`)* but also all the rows that are tied with it based on the `ORDER BY`.  So, it's functionally the same as doing `WHERE ROW_NUMBER() = 1` *(But SQL Server doesn't allow `ROW_NUMBER()` to be in a `WHERE` clause.)*

Comment: I suppose I could do a subquery and assign an ordinal value to each role. For example, PD/PI = 1, Principal Investigator = 2, etc. and then take the MIN or MAX of that.

Comment: @PaulAlbert Put your ordinals in a table, but otherwise, yeah.

Comment: Congrats on solving this three times. :-) I ended up using the last option you gave me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` with an `ORDER BY` clause in which you assign priorities to the roles.

```
SELECT user_id,
       account,
       role
       FROM (SELECT user_id,
                    account,
                    role,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id,
                                                    account
                                       ORDER BY CASE role
                                                  WHEN 'PD/PI' THEN
                                                    1
                                                  WHEN 'Principal Investigator' THEN
                                                    2
                                                  ...
                                                END) rn
                    FROM table) x
       WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use 'Limit' function if you want to retain the top row for a given selection of columns. The argument next to Limit function is for number of rows that should be returned satisfying a given query.

```
select user_id, account, role from raw_data limit 1;
```

However, if you want to retain first entry for a given userid-account-role combination, subset the data to given condition and use the limit. For ex, below patch will restrict the select query to a particular account (= 52501050) and will return the top row.

```
select user_id, account, role from raw_data where account = '52501050' limit 1;
```

Comment: `LIMIT` in `SQL Server` should be `TOP`.

Comment: @Eric - To be fair, the answer pre-dated the tag *(which was not included in the original question)*.

Comment: @MatBailie Shouldn't have answered until sure which dbms is used.

Comment: @eric You were still unnecessarily harsh in my opinion